# Running a 2-pass video conversion using Python's subprocess module and ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to convert a bunch of videos to play on my iPad. I'm using the subprocess module, which from what I understand launches a binary in a separate process from my script. I'm not sure how to handle 2-pass encoding which requires that the first process terminate before the second begin.

Here is my code:

```
def convert(filename):
  extension = filename[-3:]

  destination_filename_720 = filename[-4:] + '-a720p' + '.mp4'
  destination_filename_1080 = filename[-4:] + '-a1080p' + '.mp4'

  p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg','-i', str(filename) ,
                        '-acodec' , 'aac' ,
                        '-ab' , '160k' ,
                        '-ac' , '2' ,
                        '-vcodec' , 'libx264' ,
                        '-strict' , '-2' ,
                        '-vpre' , 'ipod640' ,
                        '-threads' , '8' ,
                        '-s' , '1280x720' ,
                        '-b:v' , '2000k' ,
                        '-pass' , '1' ,
                        '-y' ,
                        destination_filename_720])

  p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg','-i', str(filename) ,
                        '-acodec' , 'aac' ,
                        '-ab' , '160k' ,
                        '-ac' , '2' ,
                        '-vcodec' , 'libx264' ,
                        '-strict' , '-2' ,
                        '-vpre' , 'ipod640' ,
                        '-threads' , '8' ,
                        '-s' , '1280x720' ,
                        '-b:v' , '2000k' ,
                        '-pass' , '2' ,
                        '-y' ,
                        destination_filename_720])
```

As soon as the convert() function is called, both processes are spawned immediately.

The second process fails because the first process hasn't yet finished.

How can I fix this? Or, is there a better way?

Comment: Cant ffmpg operate on stdios? Can't you connect the stdout of the first process to the stdin of the second?

Comment: That's what's weird. When I run this from the shell, I see both of them being executed almost simultaneously. The second one fails, but the first one goes through. ffmpeg does not go into the backgroudn with these flags.

Comment: @tmc I had trouble doing that because the metadata isn't always at the beginning of the file. Output to stdout was fine, but input gave me issues unless the metadata was at the beginning.

Comment: If the first one goes through, and it's not in the background, then how would they be simultaneous?

Comment: if you really cant pipe from one the next, i think i would just do the first pass on the files in the dir than the second; rather than trying to do both passes on each file one at a time.

Comment: @David: subprocess.Popen is always asynchronous. You might confuse it with subprocess.call

Comment: btw, you don't need to convert the files to see them on iPad:  many players convert on the fly. You could use http://handbrake.fr/ to convert files. it has iPad preset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add p.wait() to your supprocess and it won't continue until it's completed with your first pass.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg','-i' ...etc])
p.wait()
```

For readability purposes, it may be easier to write the commands as you would do in a terminal and then just use split() to bring it into a string array. Example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
   'ffmpeg -i blah.mov -s 128x72 blah.jpg'.split())
p.wait()
```

Comment: the "".split() tip had never occurred to me, you sir are a genius!

Comment: subprocess.check_call() could be used for the first command with the same arguments. You don't need `()` around the string `"".split()` works. To support files with spaces: `[arg1, file_with_spaces_in_a_variable] + 'constant args with no shell meta chars'.split() + [argn]`

Comment: Good catch. I'll update. The extra () came from a quick copy paste where I had variables passed into the string.

Answer (score 0):

*(don't find "comment" link, so as "answer":)*

Last line should have 1080, not 720?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use pexpect because ffmpeg is not usually flushing the output